# О зависимостях программы на python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, pyinstaller, зависимости

У меня есть проект на python, где критически важен размер выходного исполняемого файла. И сейчас размер этого файла меня не удовлетворяет.

```
Использую IDE - PyCharm
Для сборки в исполняемый файл использую - Pyinstaller
Версия Python - 3.6.5
```

Подскажите, есть ли какой-нибудь инструмент, который выдаст мне все зависимости проекта? Вплоть до того, что если я, например, в каком-то из модулей использую BeautifulSoup, который использует lxml, мне выдавалась информация и о том, и о другом.

Если есть что-то такое для PyCharm, буду особо рад.

Comment: Бо́льшую часть размера исполняемого файла составляет сам интерпретатор Python. Пакеты - капля в море.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev, если только пакеты не тянут за собой библиотеки, например PyQt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, есть - `pip list` или `pip freeze`.

Чтобы увидеть дерево зависимостей, можно установить [pipdeptree](https://pypi.org/project/pipdeptree/):

```
$ pip install pipdeptree
$ pipdeptree -fl
Warning!!! Cyclic dependencies found:
------------------------------------------------------------------------
xlwt==0.7.5
ruamel.ext.rtf==0.1.1
xlrd==0.9.3
openpyxl==2.0.4
  - jdcal==1.0
pymongo==2.7.1
reportlab==3.1.8
  - Pillow==2.5.1
  - pip
  - setuptools
```

Comment: Топорно как-то работает. Вот один модуль у меня вызывает тяжёлый BeautifulSoup, но этот модуль пока что в проекте вообще нигде не используется.

Comment: Команды показывают установленные в виртуальное окружение зависимости. Если вы его не используете, то не стоило и устанавливать.

Comment: И интересно было бы видеть, что lxml у меня появляется не из воздуха, а из конкретного BeautifulSoup'а, который вызывается в конкретном файле..